# Reading project data file in Mac OS Xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, data-files

I am new to developing with XCode 9.2, writing a Cocoa app for MacOS.

I want to maintain a data file (simple CSV text file) within the program.

Lets say the file is called "the_data.dat".

This has been added to the project.

The intention is for this file to ship with the program.

Questions:

What is the path to this file when opening with fopen?
How do I ensure it gets shipped - I want it to ship as a viewable text file should we ever need to check its contents.

Comment: We need more information: is it a command line tool? If yes you can’t bundle anything with it. If it is a cocoa app you can use `Bundle`’s `path/urlForResource(named:)` (or something like that, I’m on mobile sorry) to get the path.

Comment: @HAS it is a cocoa app. I've updated the question.

Comment: What is the path to this file when opening with fopen? -> See above, never did that but it should work ... How do I ensure it gets shipped: As long as it's part of target and copied in the build phase "Copy Bundle Resources" it's shipped :)

Comment: Thanks HAS. I got the hint from your answer and used     NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *absPath= [myBundle pathForResource:@"the_file" ofType:@"dat"]; to get the path. Added the file to the project as a text file. The path resolves to ...../Contents/Resource/the_file.dat.

Comment: Glad it helped :) I don’t have the time to formulate a full answer but it’s totally fine to answer your own question and mark it as “answered” :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per HAS comment:

See comments. Hint from HAS pointed the way:

```
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *absPath= [myBundle pathForResource:@"the_file" ofType:@"dat"];
```

to get the path. Added the file to the project as a text file.

The path resolves to `...../Contents/Resource/the_file.dat`. – TenG yesterday